# Link not working on mobile device

Tags: php, html, mobile, hyperlink

So I have a normal link:

```
<a href="contactus.php">Make Enquiry</a>
```

This button works on a computer/laptop. But on a mobile device the text shows but it doesn't act as a link (i.e. it can't be clicked)

Comment: Could you create and post a jsfiddle that reproduces your issue?

Comment: got a URL we can test?

Comment: Mobile device settings preventing it? Regular links should work.

Comment: bournemouthandpooledrivinglessons.co.uk

Comment: Every other link works on the website, just not that one. It's on the top right of the page

Comment: tested on mobile - works fine

Comment: If you dont mind me asking what phone? I have iPhone 5S and the button isn't functional, is it the correct button?

Comment: android, tested firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work on my Nexus 5 or Moto G2 in Chrome or Firefox. I took to Chrome's developer tools to emulate a Nexus 5, where I was still unable to click the link.

After messing around with a few things, I was able to get it to work by adding z-index: 1; to the #smallnav CSS.

```
#smallnav {
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 190px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

I don't know if it'll work in your scenario, and this isn't the best overall solution. You've got something screwy going on in your markup/CSS causing this issue that I don't have time to fully investigate at the moment.

Comment: odd, fine on my old s5

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the float directive from css and it worked